# gamma adjustment is not working on ubuntu 21.04

Tags: xrandr, 21.04, contrast, gamma

I'm using dell with intel graphics I tried xgamma and xrandr for adjusting gamma values but both of them not working in 21.04, they are executing successfully but rgb value remains the same, it used to work fine in groovy. Is it happening cuz of the new update or some other reason? Is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Switch to *Ubuntu on Xorg* and try again. To do so, logout → click on your username → click on the settings icon at the bottom right corner and select *Ubuntu on Xorg*.